# Google Datastore can't update an entity

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm having issues retrieving an entity from Google Datastore. Here's my code:

```
    async function pushTaskIdToCurrentSession(taskId){

    console.log(`Attempting to add ${taskId} to current Session: ${cloudDataStoreCurrentSession}`);

    const transaction = datastore.transaction();
    const taskKey = datastore.key(['Session', cloudDataStoreCurrentSession]);

    try {
      await transaction.run();

      const [task] = await transaction.get(taskKey);
      let sessionTasks = task.session_tasks;
      sessionTasks.push(taskId);
      task.session_tasks = sessionTasks;

      transaction.save({
        key: taskKey,
        data: task,
      });
      transaction.commit();
      console.log(`Task ${taskId} added to current Session successfully.`);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error('ERROR:', err);
        transaction.rollback();
    }
}
```

`taskId` is a string id of another entity that I want to store in an array of a property called `session_tasks`.

But it doesn't get that far. After this line:

`const [task] = await transaction.get(taskKey);`

The error is that `task` is undefined:
`ERROR: TypeError: Cannot read property 'session_tasks' of undefined
    at pushTaskIdToCurrentSession`

Anything immediately obvious from this code?

UPDATE:

Using this instead:
`const task = await transaction.get(taskKey).catch(console.error);`
Gets me a task object, but it seems to be creating a new entity on the datastore:
[image: datastore entity error]

I also get this error:

`(node:19936) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unsupported field value, undefined, was provided. 
at Object.encodeValue (/Users/.../node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/build/src/entity.js:387:15)`

This suggests the array is unsupported?

Comment: Can you remove the destructuring assignment and show (with a `console.log`) the value of `task` after `await` ?

Comment: Updated the post with the full error.

Comment: What do you mean by 'destructuring assignment'?

Comment: Can you try this code `const task = await transaction.get(taskKey);` and show the output of `console.log(task)` ?

Comment: i did try that. Same result. Will have another go ...

Comment: [Destructuring assignement MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that **Datastore** supports two kinds of IDs.

- IDs that start with `name=` are custom IDs. And they are treated as strings
- IDs that start with `id=` are numeric auto-generated IDs and are treated as integers

When you tried to updated the value in the Datastore, the **cloudDataStoreCurrentSession** was treated as a string. Since Datastore couldn't find an already created entity key with that custom name, it created it and added `name=` to specify that it is a custom name. So you have to pass **cloudDataStoreCurrentSession** as integer to save the data properly.

If I understand correctly, you are trying to load an Array List of Strings from Datastore, using a specific Entity Kind and Entity Key. Then you add one more Task and updated the value of the Datastore for the specific Entity Kind and Entity Key.

I have create the same case scenario as yours and done a little bit of coding myself. In [this GitHub code](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Datastore/update_array_ds_transaction.js) you will find my example that does the following:

1. Goes to Datastore Entity Kind **Session**.
2. Retrieves all the data from Entity Key **id=5639456635748352** (e.g.).
3. Get's the Array List from key: **session_tasks**.
4. Adds the new task that passed from the function's arguments.
5. Performs the transaction to Datastore and updates the values.

All steps are logged in the code and there are a lot of comments explaining exactly how the code works. Also there are two examples of **currentSessionID**. One for custom names and other one for automatically generated IDs. You can test the code to understand the usage of it and modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you